# Ionic 2 Angular 2 plus How to remove parameters in URL Address?+

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

Long story short in my app the user receives an email notification which has hyperlink to open a certain record for a given id number. It looks something like this:

```
https://myappserver.com/?aid=12343551
```

The question I have is once the user opens the record is it possible to change the URL through ionic? I would like to change the url after opening and remove the parameter so it looks like this `https://myappserver.com/`

I can retrieve the URL through this.platform.url() but I don’t know how to change it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Location` from `@angular/common`. Then you can use it like:
`this.location.replaceState('/')`. Here is the [reference](https://angular.io/api/common/Location#replaceState).

Comment: Thanks worked but I had to change the URL https://myappserver.com/#/?aid=12343551 no biggie

Answer (score 0):

You could use the history function of the window object

```
window.history.pushState('', '', '/');
```

Which don't rely on Angular.